# Showing Multiple Variables in Console with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The problem is when you entry an input with scanner ,it shows on console. I want them to shown in an order. I want them shown like a matris. But with nextInt method all shows bottom of each other.

I want a console output like this:

[image: this]

But with nextInt() method your new int shows on nextLine like this:

[image: this]

How can i show multiple variables in same line with scanner?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProbilityMatrixTest {

static int M;
static int N;
static float[][] matrixX;
static float[][] matrixY;
static boolean isProbilityMatrix;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initiate();
    testMatrix(matrixX);
    System.out.println();
    multiplyMatrix();
    testMatrix(matrixY);
}

public static void initiate() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the row and column size of matrix : ");
    M = sc.nextInt();
    N = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println();


    matrixX = new float[M][N];
    System.out.println("Enter values of " + M + "x" + N + " matrix :");
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            matrixX[i][j] = sc.nextFloat();
        }
    }
}

public static void testMatrix(float[][] givenMatrix) {
    isProbilityMatrix = true;
    if (M != N) {
        isProbilityMatrix = false;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        float rowVariablesTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            rowVariablesTotal += givenMatrix[i][j];
            if (givenMatrix[i][j] < 0) {
                isProbilityMatrix = false;
            }
        }
        if (rowVariablesTotal != 1.0f) {
            isProbilityMatrix = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("TEST RESULT : ");
    if (isProbilityMatrix) {
        System.out.println("Probility matrix");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not Probility matrix");
    }
}

public static void multiplyMatrix() {

        matrixY = new float[M][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                float newMatrixVariable = 0;
                for (int a = 0; a < M; a++) {
                    newMatrixVariable += (matrixX[i][a] * matrixX[a][j]);
                }
                matrixY[i][j] = newMatrixVariable;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The square of given matrix:");
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                System.out.print(matrixY[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


}
```

}

[image: Thats]

Comment: Please show your code attempt and tell the details of your problems with this code. You understand that Scanner objects have nothing to do with display of results, that instead you will want to focus on the `System.out` methods of `PrintStream` including `print`, `println` and `printf` (the most versatile of the bunch)

Comment: I dont need to use system.out.print when showing variables on console. Scanner variable already appears on console. What i want is show them in order. But with every nextInt() method i go one line bottom. I want to show matris like:

http://prntscr.com/k43vvb

But instead it shows all bottom of each otter. 
The problem in not on print methods its on scanner showing inputs nextline always(bad english sry)

Comment: You need to actually type the values on a single line

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to decide the parts where the scanner inputs gonna write. So the inputs can look like a matris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scan entire lines at a time. Otherwise, you're always pressing the enter key, causing it to look like you're entering one value before the other on previous lines

For example, type `3 3`, then enter, then you can type three space separated decimal values, enter, then repeat that twice

```
System.out.print("Enter the row and column size of matrix : ");
String[] mn = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
int M = Integer.parseInt(mn[0]);
int N = Integer.parseInt(mn[1]);
System.out.println();

double[][] matrixX = new double[N][];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    matrixX[i] = new double[M];
    String[] row = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    for (int j = 0: j < M: j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(row[j]);
        //... 
    } 
}
```

Comment: [codePicture](http://prntscr.com/k444od) i m getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Btw you are saying i can show scanner inputs like what i want with this code right?

Comment: Enter the row **and** column size... Not sure why you typed only one number. Please try to understand what the code does before copying

Comment: Now i understand it sory. You are saying i need to write with space. I can not entry every code. Yea that works. But i think there is no way doing it with entrying every input.

Comment: Scanner will only accept input once you press the enter key, so there is no other way to format your values

Comment: So scanner has to take other input from next line it can not take it from the same line. I had to do 1 input with 2 variables in it than split it. Btw how i can found thoose split codes like "s//+" i only found that "s//" means next word i think.

Comment: It's called a regular expression pattern. `\\s` is a space. A plus afterwards means that one or more spaces

Comment: It works but i face with [this](http://prntscr.com/k44e49) problem now. It fixes when i turn floats to double. But why its not working with floats? Why it dont calculate corretctly with floats.

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer, then and post a new question after you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I didnt know you can accept answers sory. I asked here because i thought its kinda connected. Ty for your helping.

Comment: The final math calculation is not completely related to how the numbers get entered, though. Doubles have twice the "precision" as floats

Comment: Okay i am gonna read some stackOverFlow guides. And try to learn my mistakes on question asking. Ty for your caring.

Comment: I wanted to point out how numbers entered so if anyone faces the same problem they dont stuck in same place. And i didnt know you can accept answers so i edited to specify that my question resolved.

Comment: About precision. 0.1 x 0.1 is always 0.01 why it calculated 0.01000001 with floats. I didnt understand that.